# Why the performance of Redis is worse than Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, redis, hive, spark-redis

I'm using Hadoop to work on a big data project.
I can use spark to send some SQL command to Hive.
Since this process is slow, I try to write my data into Redis which is an open-source database and use spark to query my data from this database to speed up this process.
I have deployed redis server in my virtual machine, and I can use spark session to read, write and run sql command on redis by using spark-redis module.
https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis

Here's my testing script. I use spark session to get table from hive and write into redis.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import time
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName("read_and_write") \
                    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse") \
                    .enableHiveSupport() \
                    .getOrCreate()

# read table from hive
sparkDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM hive_table")
sparkDF.show()

# write table into redis
sparkDF.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis") \
             .option("table", "redis_table") \
             .mode("overwrite") \
             .save()
```

After writing process finish, I write two script to compare speed between redis and hive.
This script is to test hive:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import time, json

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName("hive_spark_test") \
                    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") \
                    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "500") \
                    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", True) \
                    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 20) \
                    .config("spark.default.parallelism", 20) \
                    .config("spark.storage.memoryFraction", 0.5) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", 0.3) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles", False) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold", 200) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.file.buffer", "32K") \
                    .config("spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight", "48M") \
                    .enableHiveSupport() \
                    .getOrCreate()

for i in range(20):
    # you can use your own sql command
    sql_command = "SELECT testColumn1, SUM(testColumn2) AS testColumn2 FROM hive_table WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-10') GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((testColumn1))"
    readDF = spark.sql(sql_command)
    df_json = readDF.toJSON()
    df_collect = df_json.collect()
    res = [json.loads(i) for i in df_collect]
    print(res)
```

Here's the result. Duration is 0.2s to 0.5s after few round.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPjQQ.jpg)

This script is to test redis:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import time, json

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName("redis_spark_test") \
                    .config("spark.redis.host", "localhost") \
                    .config("spark.redis.port", "6379") \
                    .config("spark.redis.max.pipeline.size", 200) \
                    .config("spark.redis.scan.count", 200) \
                    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "500") \
                    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", True) \
                    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 20) \
                    .config("spark.default.parallelism", 20) \
                    .config("spark.storage.memoryFraction", 0.5) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", 0.3) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles", False) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold", 200) \
                    .config("spark.shuffle.file.buffer", "32K") \
                    .config("spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight", "48M") \
                    .getOrCreate()

sql_command = """CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW redis_table (
                testColumn1 STRING,
                testColumn2 INT,
                testColumn3 STRING,
                testColumn4 STRING,
                date DATE,)
                USING org.apache.spark.sql.redis OPTIONS (table 'redis_table')
            """
spark.sql(sql_command)

for i in range(20):
    # you can use your own sql command
    sql_command = "SELECT testColumn1, SUM(testColumn2) AS testColumn2 FROM redis_table WHERE (date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-03-10') GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((testColumn1))"
    readDF = spark.sql(sql_command)
    df_json = readDF.toJSON()
    df_collect = df_json.collect()
    res = [json.loads(i) for i in df_collect]
    print(res)
```

Here's the result. Duration is 1s to 2s after few round.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTe4W.jpg)
This result is conflicted with my survey. Redis should be faster than Hive, but I get the opposite result.
**I want to know the reason and try to make Redis can run faster than Hive through Spark if that's possible.

Thank you.**

Comment: Hive is meant to be distributed, not just hosted locally with a default Derby database. If you setup a proper Hive cluster, Redis should be faster

Comment: And who knows how suboptimal the sql-to-redis translation is...